# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{|x|+3x}{|\sin x|}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{|x|+3x}{|\sin x|}$$

We have that the limit is $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{|x|+3x}{|\sin x|}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{2x}{|\sin x|}$$

In the authors' solution $|\sin x|=-\sin x$, which I do not understand. If we say $x=-a$ $(a<0)$, then $|\sin x|=|\sin (-a)|=|-\sin a|=|\sin a|=|\sin(-x)|=|-\sin x|=|\sin x|$, which is not unequivocally equal to $|\sin x|$.

Comment: It seems that you are thinking too complicated. For $-\pi < x < 0$ is $\sin(x)$ negative, therefore is $|\sin(x)| = - \sin(x)$.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you for the response, but I am not sure I get what you are saying. Is $x$ the measure of an angle, or just some number on the number line, such that $|x|\le1$?

Comment: Get concrete.  Set $x=-\frac {\pi}{6}$ and run through the claimed equality.  Does that help you see what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

$x$ is negative when $x\to 0^-$.  Therefore $\left|x\right|=-x$.
Hence
$$\lim _{x\to  0-} \frac{\left|x\right|+3x}{\left|\sin \left(x\right)\right|} =\lim _{x\to  0-}  \frac{-x+3x}{\left|\sin \left(x\right)\right|}=(*) $$

$\sin \left(x\right)$  is negative when $x\to 0-$. Therefore $\left|\sin \left(x\right)\right|=-\sin \left(x\right)$.

$$(*)=\lim _{x\to  0-} \frac{-x+3x}{-\sin \left(x\right)} =-\lim _{x\to  0-} \frac{2x}{\sin \left(x\right)}=-2\cdot1=-2  $$